# Is it possible to create angle cut using pseudo element?

Tags: css, angle

I've created a fiddle to better show what I'm trying to ask.
[angle crop of pseudo element](http://jsfiddle.net/jwhiteford/74g5vbow/1/)

Here's a image showing the desired result:

[image]

```
li.active::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    width: 10em;
    height: 100%;
    height: 20em;
    top: 5%;
    left: 15%;
    transform: rotate(-75deg);
}
```

What I'm looking to do is have the li active class display a colored background with a cropped angled at the bottom.

- it should adapt to the length of the link
- needs to see through to the background
- include the angle part within the link
- be responsive

Is this possible in pure css?

Comment: Look into using borders on element or the pseudo element. SO has truckload of such questions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I have found to do this in pure CSS is using a the `background-image` property with a linear-gradient, going from one color to transparent.

You can use the color of the element itself as a mask, or you can use the background. The difference with be how you define the gradient angle and gradient color.

In this example, I have used your object color to get the effect:
http://jsfiddle.net/948ud6f7/

You will notice it is pretty jagged and not as crisp as if you were to use an image. I am not sure of a workaround with this yet, but different browsers render the edges differently, so this at least gives you a starting point.

Good luck!

Comment: That's a pretty clever solution. I didn't think of that at all. I might be able to get this working how I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using one of three methods:

1. transform/rotate
2. border-width/border-color(transparent)
3. box-shadow